# Can Phantasmal Force Heal A Target?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, healing, illusion

*Phantasmal force* can make the target believe what they see to such an extent, they will always rationalize what they experience. This goes as far as to inflict damage on them if they experience a damaging illusion.

Reversing this, but along the same lines, can *phantasmal force* create an illusion that heals its target? For example, creating a luminous angel that heals the target, or a medic who injects a healing serum into their blood, or even just a guy with ten boxes of healing potions who stuffs one potion down their throat once per 6 seconds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes, it can heal the target. (Qualified)

There are a variety of healing (as in hit point recovery) mechanisms in the *PHB* that do not require (a) some sort of medical knowledge/skill, or (b) magic, including spending hit dice during a short rest, hit point recovery during a long rest, temporary hit points accruing to a character and/or her allies as a result of (non-magical) class features. Indeed, in the real world, the field of psychosomatic medicine is concerned with precisely the question of how one's beliefs, perceptions, emotions and state of mind influence health and healing (e.g., [*placebo effects*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placebo) are one such example).

Therefore it is reasonable to infer that *phantasmal force* can cause healing (temporary or permanent). Of course, 5th ed. D&D is predicated on rules in the broad stroke, with DM fiat, rulings or house rules on the details (for example, such healing might be ruled to require the availability and expenditure of hit dice, etc.), so of course "it's up to the DM."

One might argue that the psychic damage mechanic described in the write up for *phantasmal force* somehow indicate only a possibility of psychic harm. I disagree that there is no mechanism for healing (see my first paragraph) given the spell description's emphasis on effects on the beliefs of the target creature.

Comment: I didn't say that psychic damage isn't real.

Comment: The main problem is that, RAW, spells don't do anything they don't say they do. E.g. it might sound reasonable to light the Grease spell effect on fire, but it does not produce a flammable substance because it would say so if it did.

Comment: Not sure in 5th ed., but Grease was flammable in other editions. Also @Liesmith, saying psychic damage 'isn't real' doesn't prevent it from killing in D&D be it a sword, fireball or psychic attack, the damage is 'real'

Answer (score 29):

## No, it can't heal the target.

The damage dealt by a *phantasmal force* illusion is psychic; the target only *perceives* that it is a type appropriate to the illusion.  The target's mind is what's harmed.  Therefore, a creature's skin won't be cut just because it believes hard enough.

Conversely, there's also no mechanism by which a creature could mentally heal itself, just by believing hard enough.  Therefore, there's no way for the *phantasmal force* illusion to induce such healing.

Comment: @markovchain If you have an answer you prefer already, please use an answer post to detail it instead of multiple comments requesting this one be changed.

Comment: The closest existing mechanism would be temporary hp. You could house rule that they get temp hp until the spell ends.

Comment: It's worth noting: HP damage isn't necessarily physical injuries, it simply represents wearing down the character. Also, Purple Dragon Knight restores hit points entirely through non-magical inspiring words, so there is some precedence for hp recovery through psychological means. I still think this is probably the right (RAW/RAI) answer, since there is no mechanism provided within the spell itself and no more general rule to allow it. It's plausible for a generous DM to allow it, though.

Comment: How would you characterize the fighter's Second Wind ability, which is "a limited well of stamina that you can draw on", if not willing yourself more HP?

Answer (score 3):

### No, it can't heal the target

RAW, *phantasmal force* can only inflict damage, there is no part of the description that even implies that you can heal. This alone is enough to say no.

Supporting this is the way the damage works:

> An affected target is so convinced of the phantasm’s reality that it can even take damage from the illusion.
>
> The target perceives the damage as a type appropriate to the illusion.

This damage *does not change the physical state of the target*, they just perceive it to.

If the spell is used to "heal" the target they will believe they have been healed,  and rationalises the blood still pumping out of it's body, for instance, as being from the remaining flesh wound or whatever. However there is *no physical change in the state of the target*. When the spell ends they will find that they are still just as injured as they would have been without the spell.

Answer (score 1):

As a DM, I would rule that it can heal. If its convincing enough that belief can cause harm, then I would rule the reverse is also true. I don't think this unbalances the game in any way, since curing 1d6 per round is still average for a second level spell. Of course the affected party would first need to fail their save and believe the illusion.

Given that the rest of the party is observing actual healing - that should affect their future saves as well.

Otherwise If the healing is not real consider that the character might die while thinking they are being healed, or if the healing is temporary - they might die at the end of the spell. That doesn't make sense either.

Comment: Can you support your ruling with having used it at your table or with the rules themselves. This would also give healing magic to wizards and it seems like wotc specifically did not provide that for whatever reason.

Comment: Have used it at the table, but in Castles and Crusades rather than 5e. (which is more like Ad&d). Didn't seem to cause a balance issue.

Comment: Can whatever casts a similar spell in C&C also cast healing spells? That's honestly my biggest concern with this. It gives a class a healing capability it doesn't ordinarily get.

Comment: Illusionists in C&C can heal . . . but not themselves. They can't fool themselves with their own illusions. Perhaps another way to think of it is negative damage.