# Can healing be considered negative damage for the purpose of the Wild Magic sorcerer's Spell Bombardment?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, damage, sorcerer, healing

[Wild Magic sorcerers](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#WildMagic) get the Spell Bombardment feature at 18th level (PHB, p. 103):

> When you roll damage for a spell and roll the highest number possible on any of the dice, choose one of those dice, roll it again and add that roll to the damage. You can use the feature only once per turn.

By multiclassing, feats, magic items or wish, it is possible for a Wild Magic Sorcerer to cast healing spells such as *cure wounds*.

**Can healing damage rolls be considered “negative damage rolls” for the purpose of Spell Bombardment (granting an additional healing die if one of the dice gets rolled at max value)?**

Comment: Related on [Is there an official rule that the minimum damage can't be negative?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108178/is-there-an-official-rule-that-the-minimum-damage-cant-be-negative)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## No, healing is not "negative damage".

There is no 'negative damage' mechanic in 5e, so healing is healing and damage is damage.

Comment: Arh... It made perfect sense to me. At least I get to feel stupid now instead of later on.

Comment: @GaelL It's a reasonable question! (Especially if one's experiences of, for example, the undead in previous versions of D&D saw healing spells as directly offensive :). And even keeping one's perspective squarely on 5th edition, [damage and healing and magic can be counterintuitive](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/82533/can-phantasmal-force-heal-a-target/82546#82546).

Answer (score 6):

No, healing is healing and damage is damage. They're two different things.

The only place Spell Bombardment *might* help, sort of, is the [*life transference*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/life-transference) spell from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 160 (normally available to only clerics and wizards).  It deals 4d8 necrotic damage to you, then heals somebody else for twice the damage you took - so in that case Spell Bombardment could increase the damage you take, and thus increase the healing you do (at cost of your own HP, obviously).